# Simple Parallel Electric Circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

Ammeter (A1) and voltmeter (V) in series have parallel connection to another ammeter (A2). Currents in A1 and A2 are respectively 0.2 and 1.7 amp. Voltmeter's voltage is 6 volts.

[image]

How should I find resistances of all elements?

Comment: Hint: Resistance = Voltage/Current

Comment: Hi L P. If you show more effort & help us understand what concept you're having trouble with, your question is less likely to be closed.

Comment: Hi BMS.
I found, that because of series $I_{V}=I_{1}=0.2$ and from here $R_{V}=\frac{U_{V}}{I_{V}}=30$<br/>
and for currents:
$$U_{1}+U_{V}=U_{2}$$
$$R_{1}I_{1}+U_{V}=R_{2}I_{2}$$
after this I can't continue to find $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$

Comment: @LP Is the question complete?Can you tell if there's anything more to it?

Comment: Thank You @Aditya !
It was my cousin's homework and as you assumed, both ammeters were identical, but at first time he forgot to tell about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's a way to solve its by assuming both ammeters to be identical and thus from your equations:$$0.2R+6=1.7R\\\implies R=4$$

- because there's no other relation between them, or if you find one it'll be the same information disguised in other form.
- or it can be solved if we have any bit extra information; as to solve a linear equation in two variables we need two independent equations/information.